# Open a Workbook with dynamic name

Tags: excel, vba

I am working in a project of VBA, and I need to open some Workbooks, but the name is kind of dynamic, but only the last name. Sometimes the name comes like "OnHand 066 May" and sometimes with "OnHand 006 Jun"

```
Dim Dir As String
Dir = ActiveWorkbook.Path
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `Dir` as a variable name. It is a reserved function name.

Use a wildcard with the `Dir` function to find a file that matches.

The `Dir` function will not return a full path, so you have to append it again if you want to actually open the file.

Let's assume there is only one file in that folder that matches, as you did not specify that in your question.

```
Dim sFile As String

sFile = Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\OnHand*.xls*")

If sFile <> "" Then
  ' if you get an error on the next line, someone else may have it open already
  Debug.Print "About to open: " & ActiveWorkBook.Path & "\" & sFile
  WorkBooks.Open ActiveWorkBook.Path & "\" & sFile
Else
  MsgBox "Cannot find a file like that"
End If
```

Comment: When I try to run it, it says "Expected array", do you know what that means and how can i solve it?

Comment: I just solved this problem... i was using the 'DIR' still, and didn't put the folder where the workbook will be stay... thank you very much!